# Persistant Volume is not available in Volume Attachment

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to expose the Blob Storage to Kubernetes pods. During the testing, I got the below error

> Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[blob-secret],
> unattached volumes=[secrets-store]: error processing PVC
> namespace/pvc-blob-claim: PVC is being deleted

Then I executed the below command for debugging

```
kubectl get pv 

pv-blob   10Gi       RWX            Retain  



kubectl get volumeattachment

I got none <pv-blob is not available here>
```

May I know why the PV is not available under Volume Attachment ?  Any suggestions on debugging the scenario are much appreciated.

Comment: can you describe your pv?